# openGL rotation reset

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I am currently viewing a set of spheres and rotating them around x, y, z when the button x, y or z is pressed respectively. Rotation works. But when I reset my rotations with i, I don't always get a perfect reset.

```
case 'x':
case 'X':
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glutSetWindow(windowID[0]);
        glRotatef(1, 1, 0, 0);
        glutPostRedisplay();

        xRotation++;
        break;

case 'y':
case 'Y':
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glutSetWindow(windowID[0]);
        glRotatef(1, 0, 1, 0);
        glutPostRedisplay();

        yRotation++;
        break;

case 'z':
case 'Z':
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glutSetWindow(windowID[0]);
        glRotatef(1, 0, 0, 1);
        glutPostRedisplay();

        zRotation++;
        break;

case 'i':
case 'I':
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glutSetWindow(windowID[0]);
        glRotatef(-xRotation, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(-yRotation, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(-zRotation, 0, 0, 1);
        glutPostRedisplay();
```

Rotating works perfectly. Each increment, I add the increment to the respective float (x\y\z)Rotation to store how many increments I have made around the axis, which I then use to reset back to origin.

I have figured out my problem is when I rotate along 2 or more axis. It appears as if I am also only having this problem along a single axis at a time.

Each window is drawn with

```
void DrawWindowOne()
{
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glViewport(0, 0, 250, 250);
DrawAxis(1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
DrawSpheres();

glViewport(250, 0, 250, 250);
DrawAxis(1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);

DrawSpheres();

glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);

glViewport(500, 0, 250, 250);
DrawAxis(1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnable(GL_LIGHT2);

DrawSpheres();

glDisable(GL_LIGHT2);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What samgak had said to answer your question will work, however this is something to be aware of and is good to know about to prevent pitfalls later on, when your project becomes large and complex.

When working with rotations in 3D space and requiring to rotate about any given axis [X,Y,Z] where in the translation-rotation matrix the rotation is done using Euler Angles there is a known problem that arises. This problem is called Gimbal Lock. Take your sphere for instance a 3D Model that you would like to rotate about any axis; before you begin rotating imagine having a circle or a ring that is larger then your sphere and is placed parallel to each axis. We can say that our X-Axis ring has a handle to grab that is pointing to the Right or East, your Y-Axis ring has a handle that is pointing Up or to the North, and your Z-Axis ring is pointing at you. As you grab a handle and you begin to move it that ring will rotate the object on that axis.

Imagine your sphere is the Earth:

- X-Axis: when you rotate your 3D model this will make it rotate about the x-axis East & West and the Earth will turn with the North & South Poles and Equator changing directions. If you Are looking down the Z-Axis(LookAt) the equator will tilt or rotate towards and away from you
- Y-Axis when you rotate your 3D model this will make it rotate about the
  y-axis North & South and the Earth will rotate around the poles like as in the Earth's Days. The Equator doesn't move.
- Z-Axis when you rotate your 3D model this will make it rotate about the z-axis "LookAt" (still horizontal but perpendicular to East & West) and the Earth will rotate about the LookAt axis and the North & South Poles & Equator will change direction. Looking down the LookAt axis you will see the Poles And Equator tilt towards the East and West.

An analogy here to demonstrate this a little more as in the motion of the rings to rotating your 3D Model: I will use a motor cycle, think of the rotation of axis as the following

- X-Axis - The Bikes Throttle
- Y-Axis - Turning the Handle Bars
- Z-Axis - Leaning the Bike Left & Right

NOTE: As you rotate your object about any axis the rings move with the object showing you the rotation.

Now that you have a visual of what is happening with each rotation, I will demonstrate Gimbal Lock with Euler Angels. We will leave the Y-Axis alone, and it doesn't matter if we use the X or Z axis here. I will use the Z-Axis since we are looking down it and as you rotate the object you can see it rotating left and right. Let us Rotate This Object 90 degrees or PI/2 in either direction (CW, CCW) now our Z-Axis Ring is now rotated with the object and since we were using the Earth, we still see the same area of land in front of us, but the Equator is now where the poles were and the poles are now where the equator was. We have not touched the other two axis and did not rotate. But if you notice, you will see that the Z-Axis Ring is now aligned with The X-Axis. Now if we begin to rotate about the X-Axis the Z-Axis is now rotating with it. We have lost a Dimension of Freedom to Rotate. This is what the term Gimbal Lock is referred to.

If we reset everything back, this can happen in 6 different combinations between the 3 axis. So no matter which way you try rotate freely in all 3 Dimensions using only 3D mathematics or 3D Rotation Matrices that are using Euler Angles; which are your basic matrices that use the sine and cosine functions to do the rotations about each axis, you will always have cases of Gimbal Lock.

There is a way to avoid this! Using Quaternions! The math to them is a little tricky to understand for it is a 4D vector type and it does involve the imaginary plane and complex numbers, however the programming of them is quite easier since they closely resemble both vectors and matrices. Having this 4th component lets you freely rotate about (X,Y,Z) without having this problem.  There are plenty of resources out there on Gimbal Lock and Quaternions for both the Math and the programming of them and many decent math libraries already exist that already have quaternions defined for you, it is just a matter of reading their documentations on how to apply them in your code. They make life a lot easier.

One thing to be aware of is, You do not have to always use Quaternions when rotating in 3D space, it always depends on the need. Here are some examples when it is better to use Quaternions and when using Euler Angles are okay.

Euler Angles: If you know you will be rotating on one axis only.

- A barrel rolling on the ground
- A child's swing
- A seesaw
- A Rocking Chair

Quaternion Rotations: When you need freedom of 2 or more axis.

- Camera Rotations
- A ball rolling on the ground.
- A plane or a jet flying.
- A Space Shuttle or Satellite moving in Space.
- A Submarine
- Character AI - Detection and Following Algorithms When Height is a Factor!
- Any Character Movement when Height is also a factor. Bird flying, Fish Swimming, Character Animation - Ragdoll Physics.

Here is a link to a video describing Gimbal Lock which is a very precise and detailed view to completely understand this phenomenon in less then 10 minutes. [YouTube: Gimbal Lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno)

Comment: If you want a very nice math library to work with try GLM it works very good with OpenGL and GLSL language for the naming convention and function calls are very close. It is a headers only library. One thing to be careful as they progressed through their versions at a certain point they changed their model as to any function that accepts a value as an angle is now strictly defined as being in radians and no longer in degrees.

Comment: (continued...)  If you are using their newest version make sure you are passing in your angle as radians or you can use one of their functions to convert angles into radians and pass that into their functions as its parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your matrix calling

```
glLoadIdentity();
```

instead of this code:

```
glRotatef(-xRotation, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(-yRotation, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(-zRotation, 0, 0, 1);
```

The problem you are having is that matrix rotations are not transitive. Rotating around x and then y is not the same as rotating around y and then x. If you are allowing the user to make multiple interactive incremental rotations around each of the axes using the keys, then it's not possible to simply accumulate the angles in 3 variables and undo the rotations by rotating by a negative amount around each of the axes. You would have to store which order the rotations occurred in and how much each time. So it's far easier to just reset the matrix to identity.

Comment: On my first window this fixes it all up. But I have two other windows that are to reflect identical changes, and instead it clears the window and just shows me the clear colour

Comment: glLoadIdentity will wipe out any model to world transform you may have loaded in addition to any rotations you are applying, so you will need to reload them if so

Comment: if all three windows are loading the exact same model in the exact same way, shouldn't that also have effected the first window?

Comment: Yes, it should. It's hard to say without knowing what your window code is like. The code you posted looks like it only deals with the first window (windowID[0])

Comment: I've added the draw code to my original question. I have copied the same code across each window, with a few lines omitted where I directly changed the lights

Comment: Do you perform any matrix operations on the model view matrix when you initialize the app? It doesn't make much sense to me that resetting the model view matrix to identity is causing problems in some windows but not another, but if you just set it up again exactly how it is at the start it should work. Also, make sure you are calling glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); before glLoadIdentity() so you don't end up nuking your projection matrix instead or anything like that (it doesn't seem likely from your code that's the case though)

Comment: Brilliant. I was having a differant issue earlier, and the suggested solution seemed to include loading lookat into the modelview matrix. This fixed my earlier issues but Im assuming this meant I was also resetting my view with loadIdentity.

Ive moved lookat to projection matrix and that solved my problem. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Don't accumulate your rotations in the modelview matrix with repeated calls to Rotate(1,1,0,0), instead increment a variable when a key is pressed and then use Rotate(angle_x,1,0,0) after you have set the identity matrix once per update. Otherwise overtime you will get matrix drift where small rounding errors will cause your rotation matrix to degenerate.

resetting your object would just mean setting angle_x = 0.0f;

Also don't put your lookat matrix in the projection matrix as this will cause unexpected results further down the line. see http://sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html for a complete description.

Normally you set the projection matrix once before your mainloop.

Then each loop you set the current matrix to modelview. then for each object you want to draw set the modelview matrix to lookat * model.

I would also recommend reading how opengl uses the various matrices [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)